# Should I move my linux swap partition closer to my ext4 partition?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot

I am installing both linux mint and win 7 on the same disk on an old machine, I first installed linux (I know I should have installed win first so I wouldn't have to fix grub later but well, it's done now), and I let the installer format the HDD and setup the partitions.

Now I am resizing the main (ext4) partition in half, to create a NTFS one for installing windows on it, but my swap partition will be at the end of the disk. The partitions look something like this now:

**||---------- EXT4 (247GB) ----------|---------- NTFS (247GB) ----------|- SWAP (5GB) -||**

Should I move the swap partition to the start or in the middle of the other two partitions? Or it doesn't really matters?

Comment: Theoretically, you might have some impact if the swap drive is physically located near the linux partition.  It would reduce the head movement, which is one of the slower parts of the hard disk read/write cycle.  In reality, it probably doesn't make a significant difference.  Still, I would recommend placing the swap space immediately after the ext4 partition.

Comment: @DavidPaige Thanks, I ended up doing that, if you want to post an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, you might have some impact if the swap drive is physically located near the linux partition. It would reduce the head movement, which is one of the slower parts of the hard disk read/write cycle. In reality, it probably doesn't make a significant difference. Still, I would recommend placing the swap space immediately after the ext4 partition.

Comment: By default, the Debian installer also adds the swap after ext4 but I noticed by doing that, there is a free space left of 728.6 kB at the end. This does not happen by adding the swap before ext4. Any idea why?